# Avoid restarting each time a dtsx package locks in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis, ssdt-bi

This is driving me crazy. I'm using SSDT-BI for Visual Studio 2013 and have to restart my machine each time a dtsx package is locked. There is a good post on how to get around this for [SSIS 2012](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/the-process-cannot-acces-file.html) , but can't find anything on how to fix the problem for 2013. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

OK, A stupid mistake, should have been running SSDT-BI on Visual Studio 2012 in this client environment as they are using SQL Server 2012. SSDT-BI on VS2013 doesn't work properly with SQL Server 2012, requires SQL Server 2014.
Perhaps this will help someone!